# GKLeaderboard Rotating Parent View Controller

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, ios6, gamekit

I am trying to present a GKLeaderboardViewController on another view controller that contains an EAGL View. The view presents fine but rotates the parent view 90 degrees counterclockwise, as well as breaking touch responsiveness and other functionality of the parent view controller. The GKLeaderboardViewController also gets dismissed fine. Here is the code used to create the parent view:

```
    viewController = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

//
// Create the EAGLView manually
//  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
//  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
//
//
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];

// attach the openglView to the director
glView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
[director setOpenGLView:glView];


//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
//  if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
//      CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");

//
// VERY IMPORTANT:
// If the rotation is going to be controlled by a UIViewController
// then the device orientation should be "Portrait".
//
// IMPORTANT:
// By default, this template only supports Landscape orientations.
// Edit the RootViewController.m file to edit the supported orientations.
//
//#ifdef _ARM_NEON_
//#define ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM CCQuadParticleSystem //used to be CCQuadParticleSystem
//#elif _ARM_|| TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
//#define ARCH_OPTIMAL_PARTICLE_SYSTEM CCPointParticleSystem
//#else
//#error(unknown architecture)
//#endif

[director setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];
[director setDisplayFPS:NO];
[viewController.view addSubview:glView];

[viewController.view sendSubviewToBack:glView];
[window addSubview:viewController.view];
[window setRootViewController:viewController];


[[ZGCGKHelper sharedGameKitHelper]setViewController:viewController];

[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I am presenting the leaderboard view like so:

```
    -(void) presentViewController:(UIViewController*)vc
    {

   UIViewController* rootVC = [self getRootViewController];
   [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
    [rootVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^(void){
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] startAnimation];

}];
```

}

The notifications displayed by game center orient themselves correctly and don't interfere with the EAGLView but the leaderboard view does. Any ideas on how to fix this? This issue arose after upgrading to iOS 6.

Comment: What your cocos2d version number?

Comment: I fixed it. They have fixed this issue in the newest version of cocos2d. I replaced shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation with shouldAutorotate and got the current rotation using [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation]. I also overode the supportedInterfaceOrientations and returned UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown.